# Gradle copy local jar into cache

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need some help understanding why my build.gradle does not copy locally referred jar into its cache. On Windows, I expected to see jars in C:\Users\myusername .gradle and indeed other JARs are there.

I can't import this JAR in IntelliJ as it does not find it.

Side question: did anybody figure out how to debug Gradle's DSL? I set up remote debugging and IntelliJ never hits my breakpoint. It does not the have the checkbox on it so I guess IDE does not think it is code.

Few things are not making sense to me:

```
 1. gradle dependencies --configuration compile

  \--- com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
     ....

  MY_JAR_1.0.1.jar is not present. 

 2. gradle copyDependencies - this task finds and copies it.
    task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'dependencies'
    }

 3. This task also finds my jar. 
    task listcompile << {
        configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
    }

Why does #1 not find it?

    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //flatDir {
        //    dirs 'customlibs'
        //}
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.5-jre'
        compile files('customlibs/MY_JAR_1.0.1.jar')
    }

    task listcompile << {
        configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
    }

    // copy all dependencies into this folder
    task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'dependencies'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Gradle's `dependencies` task will only display modules that have a defined group:name:version coordinate. You are adding a file directly, with no associated identifier.

What you can do instead is add a flat directory repository and declare your custom JAR as a normal dependency, like so:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'customlibs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ':MY_JAR:1.0.1'
}
```

You will need to rename the JAR so that it matches the naming convention for Maven/Gradle, i.e. *MY_NAME-1.0.1.jar* (replacing the last underscore with a hyphen).